# Escribir en input search al seleccionar fecha input data-type="date" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

**Escribur en input Search al seleccionar fecha en input type=date**

*Hola mi consulta es la siguiente, No logro que al seleccionar la fecha de un input data-type="date" o type text, se escriba en el input serach de datatable*

```
<input autocomplete="off" data-firstday="0" data-startmode="day" data-type="date" data-dformat="YYYY-MM" data-sformat="MM-YYYY" data-mindate="" data-maxdate="" data-opendays="" data-openhours="" data-startcalendar="" data-endcalendar="" data-size="" data-inline="0" data-ampm="1" data-disableminute="0" data-popuppos="top center" placeholder="" name="seleccione_periodo" id="seleccione_periodo" value="" type="text" data-calendar="1" class="">

$(document).ready(function() {


$('#seleccione_periodo').change(function () {
$('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').val($(this).val());
$('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').trigger('keyup');
});

} );
```

[image: Ejemplo de la consulta]

Answer (score 0):

Asignale un id al input search y cuando se ejecute el evento pasas como valor la fecha de tu input date

```
$('#seleccione_periodo').change(function (event) {
$('#id-search').val(event.target.value)
});
```

Comment: input[type="search"]' - Es el input que viene por defecto datatables. no tiene ni ID ni Name para seleccionarlo

Comment: entonces intenta enviando el event target a la función como la tienes y en el val asignas el event.target.value